# Java for-loop generating MAC addresses

Tags: java, for-loop, mac-address

Trying to make a loop of MAC address values with:

```
String macAddr = "AA:BB:CC:DD:";
char[] chars = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
String[] strings = {"0", "0", "0", "0"};

for (int i=0; i<strings.length; i++)
{
    //counter from 0 to F
    for (int d = 0; d <= 9; d++)
    {
        strings[i] = ""+d;
        print();
    }
    for (int d = 0; d< chars.length; d++)
    {
        strings[i] = ""+chars[d];
        print();
    }
}
```

where print() is:

```
System.out.println(macAddr+strings[3]+strings[2]+":"+strings[1]+strings[0]);
```

But i'm getting run-over:

AA:BB:CC:DD:00:0D
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:0E
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:0F
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:0F
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:1F
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:2F
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:3F

The two problems are the dual values at each crossover (e.g. AA:BB:CC:DD:00:0F)
and the values stopping at F on each value.

I'm trying to get them as:

AA:BB:CC:DD:00:0D
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:0E
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:0F
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:11
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:12
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:13

etc.

Cheers :)

Comment: Why not just count to 16 and convert to hex?

Comment: Didn't know how to, that's why the answer below got my "Answered". Simple solution to exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this for keeping it simple:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String macAddr = "AA:BB:CC:DD:";
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
            String fullAddr = String.format(macAddr + "%02X:%02X", i, j);
            System.out.println(fullAddr);
        }
    }
}
```

Output (abbreviated):

```
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:00
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:01
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:..
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:10
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:0A
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:..
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:0F
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:10
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:..
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:FF
AA:BB:CC:DD:01:00
AA:BB:CC:DD:..:..
AA:BB:CC:DD:FF:FF
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a `long` to store your mac address and create a small function to convert it to a `String`.

```
public static String toMacString(long mac) {

    if (mac > 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFL || mac < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("mac out of range");

    StringBuffer m = new StringBuffer(Long.toString(mac, 16));
    while (m.length() < 12) m.insert(0, "0");

    for (int j = m.length() - 2; j >= 2; j-=2)
        m.insert(j, ":");
    return m.toString().toUpperCase();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long mac = 0xAABBCCDD0000L;

    for (long i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        System.out.println(toMacString(mac++));
}
```

Example output:

```
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:00
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:01
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:02
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:03
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:04
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:05
AA:BB:CC:DD:00:06
....
AA:BB:CC:DD:03:DF
AA:BB:CC:DD:03:E0
AA:BB:CC:DD:03:E1
AA:BB:CC:DD:03:E2
AA:BB:CC:DD:03:E3
AA:BB:CC:DD:03:E4
AA:BB:CC:DD:03:E5
AA:BB:CC:DD:03:E6
AA:BB:CC:DD:03:E7
```

Comment: Add a `toUpperCase()` and the result should be perfect. :) (+1)

Comment: Thomas: Good point, fixed! @Maurice Perry: Fixed before your comment was posted.. ;)

Comment: @MauricePerry: Updated anyways with a out of range check.

Comment: A good way to do it, but complex for a beginner, @Bohemian's answer was more along the lines of a modification of what I had.

Comment: @spuriosity heh, okey.. I would however recommend you to represent your mac as a `long` or `byte[]` wrapped in a "`Mac`" class.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] Mac = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
    Random rd = new Random();
    rd.nextInt(15);
    String result="";

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        String a = Mac[rd.nextInt(15)];
        String b = Mac[rd.nextInt(15)];
        result+=a+b;
        if(i<5){
            result+=":";
        }

    }
```